# How to find references PsiElement AppCode Plugin Development

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, appcode

How we can find all the references of an existing PsiElement. Specifically a `SwiftFunctionDeclaration`. I've tried with

`ReferencesSearch.search(functionDeclaration, ProjectScope.getProjectScope(functionDeclaration.getProject())).findAll();`

But it will not work if the method is an interface method, and it's accessed through Protocol reference instead of concrete class.

Example:

```
protocol Test {
func calculate()
}

class TestingClass : Test {
func calculate() {
 }
}
```

So if I'm using something like that, `let s = TestingClass(), s.calculate()` it will find that `calculate` method has references. But if I'm softening the reference `let s: Test = TestingClass(), s.calculate()` it will tell me that `calculate` method inside of `TestClass` doesn't have any references.

The question is: is there an API which will give me the references even if used through Protocol. If not, is there possible to find if a `SwiftFunctionDeclaration` is an implementation method of a specific Protocol?

Comment: Take a look at `SwiftSuperDeclarationSearch.getAllSuperMethods`

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly the answer!!! If you add your answer as a response I will accept as the one correct. Appreciate your help.